# Как закрыть от индексации часть текста?

Tags: seo

Ни кто не подскажет как можно скрыть часть текста от индексации, например в Yandex noindex, а как быть с гуглом?

Comment: Если не совру: гугл не индексирует блоки у которых display: none, потом JavaScript менять стиль.  
Как вариант можно подгружать аяксом.

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае никак, `noindex` гугл игнорирует, а `<!--googleoff: index-->` не работает для веба. Самый дубовый и надёжный вариант, лишённый всех недостатков вариантов с динамическим изменением текста на стороне клиента: формировать текст на сервере в зависимости от юзерагента. Правда, так теряется возможность кэширования страниц, но задача - решается.

Comment: _"формировать текст на сервере в зависимости от юзерагента"_ - за такое гугл понижает в рейтинге.

Comment: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html _"If you pre-render pages, make sure that the content served to Googlebot matches the user's experience, both how it looks and how it interacts. **Serving Googlebot different content than a normal user would see is considered cloaking, and would be against our Webmaster Guidelines.**"_